# Unity3D ScrollView/ScrollBar from bottom to top

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollbar, scrollview

I'm trying to create a terminal emulator in Unity. I'm able to enter text and have it displayed as output above, and the output will generate a scrollbar when enough text is entered via a ScrollView.

However I can't figure out how to make the scrollbar jump to the bottom when a user enters text.

This is the method used to draw the GUI Window.

```
// relevant instance variables
    private Rect _windowPosition = new Rect();
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            string user_input = "";
            Vector2 scroll_pos = new Vector2(1,1);

        ...
        ...
        ...

    private void onWindow(int windowID){
                GUILayout.BeginVertical();

            // Output is placed here. Is Scrollable
                scroll_pos = GUILayout.BeginScrollView( scroll_pos );
                GUILayout.Label( String.Join("\n", output.ToArray()) );
                GUILayout.EndScrollView();
            // Output ends here. Next piece is user input

                user_input = GUILayout.TextField(user_input);
                if (Event.current.Equals(Event.KeyboardEvent("return"))) {
                    output.Add(user_input);
                    user_input = ""; //clears the TextField
                    scroll_pos.x = 1;
                    scroll_pos.y = 1;
                }
                GUILayout.EndVertical();
                GUI.DragWindow();
            }
```

From my searching, I'd seen it said that I should just change the scroll_pos variable, since that's used to control/read the scrollbar's position. The scrollbar's value is normalized between 0 - 1.

I've tried forcing the scroll_pos values to be both, 0 and 1, but it has no impact. Beyond this I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: Your best solution would be to dump the pre-4.6 UI system and just design one in the 4.6+ system which will take you far less time, be more processor efficient, and look far better to boot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcU8yzv_xEw  --- why on earth people would use OnGUI now is absolutely beyond me, there are zero benefits to it.  Did you know OnGUI is called multiple times per frame?

Comment: Know what slows down Kerbal Space Program?  It's not the procedurally generated meshes or the advanced physics calculations they do to determine if your ship falls apart from aerodynamic forces... It's OnGUI.

Comment: I'm not kidding - apply your OnGUI skills to custom editor work and don't put it in your game: http://www.mindthecube.com/blog/2010/09/avoiding-performance-cost-of-ongui  --- Every time OnGUI is called it creates a huge mess of object which it immediately disposes of after each call.  This causes the garbage collector to work overtime throwing out huge numbers of created objects and causes huge CPU spikes in your game.  The new UI system doesn't even remotely come close to being this bad (in fact it's great) and you can make your UI 3d to boot.

Comment: I'll look into this. This is my first entry into Unity3D Scripting. I'll be honest, a lot of this GUI stuff seems really strange to me. I was expecting something more like Java where I'd have a reference to a Window or Frame object which I could manipulate, but Unity just seems to recreate everything for each frame as far as I can tell. And I do believe that this is a huge bottleneck for KSP. Simply dragging around any GUI Window in game causes massive amounts of lag for me. Thank you for giving me some insight that I'm not just looking at this all wrong

Comment: "This is my first entry into Unity3D Scripting."  Learning to script on the old UI system is basically a waste of time - the Editor itself uses it so it's useful for custom editor stuff, but other than that worthless.  The whole point of the 4.6 UI system is that it's not all created every frame and you can visually design some of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d_l9OmLYTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
scroll_pos.x = 1;
scroll_pos.y = 1;
```

to

```
scroll_pos.y += 9999;
```

if you want to force scroll on horizontal do it with X too but usually consoles doesn't generates horizontal scroll, they force line breaks based on how many columns you configure.

Comment: This solved it. How odd. I wouldn't think I'd need to add anything beyond 1 since the value of a scrollbar is normalized between 0 and 1.

Comment: This is not an elegant solution but is the easiest that works fine ^^

Comment: Yeah definitely haha. It's certainly good enough for me. I'm just playing around learning C# by building a plugin for a game.

Comment: It's not actually normalized between 0 and 1. Where I'm using it it went up to 3500. It seems to be a pixel distance or something similar

Comment: If you really want to be sure you can/should use `float.MaxValue` instead ;)